# How to retrieve and update data from visualforce to apex controller

Tags: apex, visualforce, update, upsert

I don't have problem on retrieving data. But on updating the fields. I'm curios on how to do it.I tried something but seems not working.

This is my apex Code:

```
public class ProntoEventSettingsController {

    List<ProntoEVents_Setting__c> settings;
    public String X2 { get; set; }

    public ProntoEventSettingsController (){
    }

    public List<ProntoEVents_Setting__c> getSettings() {
        if(settings == null) {

           settings = [SELECT Id, Name, Available_Credits__c, Digital_Key__c, Gateway__c, Record_Events_to_Opportunities__c,Stages_for_Failed_Process__c,Stages_for_In_Progress__c,Stages_for_Successful_Process__c  FROM ProntoEVents_Setting__c Limit 1];
        }

        return settings;
    }

    public List<SelectOption> getopenPresentationOptions(){

        List<SelectOption> optns = new List<Selectoption>();

       optns.add(new SelectOption('','--None--'));
       optns.add(new SelectOption('Prospecting','Prospecting'));
       optns.add(new SelectOption('Qualification','Qualification'));
       optns.add(new SelectOption('Needs Analysis','Needs Analysis'));
       optns.add(new SelectOption('Value Proposition','Value Proposition'));
       optns.add(new SelectOption('Id. Decision Makers','Id. Decision Makers'));
       optns.add(new SelectOption('Perception Analysis','Perception Analysis'));
       optns.add(new SelectOption('Proposal/Price Qoute','Proposal/Price Qoute'));
       optns.add(new SelectOption('Negotiation/Review','Negotiation/Review'));
       optns.add(new SelectOption('Closed Won','Closed Won'));
       optns.add(new SelectOption('Closed Lost','Closed Lost'));

       return optns;
    }


    public PageReference save() { 
      return null;
    }

}
```

and this is my VF code.
Just want to try to update the checkbox and the SelectOption.

```
<apex:form>
                        <div class="form-horizontal">
                            <apex:repeat var="setting" value="{!settings}">
                             <label class="control-label"><apex:inputCheckbox styleClass="opp-checkbox" value="{!setting.Record_Events_to_Opportunities__c}" />&nbsp;&nbsp;Record Events to Opportunities</label>
                            <div class="form-details">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Stage for In-Progress:</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                                        <apex:selectList value="{!setting.Stages_for_In_Progress__c}" size="1" styleClass="form-control"> 
                                            <apex:selectOptions value="{!openPresentationOptions}" /> 
                                        </apex:selectList>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Stage for Successful Process:</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                                        <apex:selectList value="{!setting.Stages_for_Successful_Process__c}" size="1" styleClass="form-control"> 
                                            <apex:selectOptions value="{!openPresentationOptions}" /> 
                                        </apex:selectList>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Stage for Failed Process:</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                                        <apex:selectList value="{!setting.Stages_for_Failed_Process__c}" size="1" styleClass="form-control"> 
                                            <apex:selectOptions value="{!openPresentationOptions}" /> 
                                        </apex:selectList>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="button-container pull-right">
                                    <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save" id="theButton"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            </apex:repeat>
                        </div>
                        </apex:form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to update your object in your save method...

```
public PageReference save() { 
     update settings;      
     return null;
}
```

And check one more thing you should use

```
List<ProntoEVents_Setting__c> settings{set;}
```